# Stuck on defining the limit

Tags: limits

Can't figure out, what to start with to define the following limit:
$$
    \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} e^{-x^2} x^{x \log^2(x)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $x=e^{\log x}$. Using this you can simplify the expresion to $e^{P(x)}$ where $P(x)$ is an expression in $x$ and $\log x$. Then investigate the limit $P$ of that $P(x)$ expression. You will find $P = - \infty$, implying that your limit is $0$.

Comment: Your answer means I was going in the correct direction. However still not sure how I investigate $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} xlog^3x-x^2$ which I got after the modification you suggested

Comment: You could try to show or perhaps you can use that $x - \log^3 x \ge 1$ for sufficiently large $x$. [That it is greater 1 is is not very important; you just want that it is positive and does not tend to 0.]